# How can I disconnect Javascript in iframe or overwrite class in iframe

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to ask how I can do this?

I have a site in an `iframe` from another site, which displays 2 red `<div>` elements. They have their own class `.red`. Is there any way to override the `class="red"` part to another class from my website?

Or can I disconnect Javascript in this `iframe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the DOM in the `iframe` after `load` of your resources you could overwrite a `function` in the `global` scope like this:

```
window.myFunction = function(arg){
      // implementation
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), which governs how much you are allowed to manipulate the contents of an iframe.

In short, if the iframe is displaying a page from another domain, you'll not be able to modify its DOM.